# AutoMapper 12.0 Throwing Unknown LINQ expression of type 'Default' when using ProjectTo

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

We're in the process of doing a large .net upgrade (moving from 4.8 to 7) and we're having issues with some of our projections. This was all working just fine with automapper 8 and .net 4.8, but since upgrading to 12 we now get `NotSupportedException: Unknown LINQ expression of type 'Default'.` when trying to project to an entity that has optional related children.

Feels like what we're doing is pretty basic so not sure what's going wrong.

Entity:

```
[Table("PaymentUploads")]
public class PaymentUpload
{
    [Key]
    [Column("PaymentUploadId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public byte[] RawFileContents { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ProcessedOn { get; set; }
    public Guid? ProcessedById { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProcessedById")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser? ProcessedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Dto:

```
public class PaymentUploadDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPaymentAmount { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ProcessedOn { get; set; }
    public Guid? ProcessedById { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUserPreview? ProcessedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Profile:

```
CreateProjection<PaymentUpload, PaymentUploadDto>();
```

Request:

```
DbContext.PaymentUploads.AsNoTracking().Where(g => g.CreatedOn >= createdOnOrAfter).ProjectTo<PaymentUploadDto>(Mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
```

If we change the profile to:

```
CreateProjection<PaymentUpload, PaymentUploadDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ProcessedBy, opt => opt.DoNotAllowNull());
```

Then as long as every `ProcessedById` column entry has a value everything returns as expected, but if any do contain `null` for the ProcessedById now it instead throws: `'The cast to value type 'System.Guid' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.'` All of the associated properties seem to be properly declared as nullable so we aren't sure why that's not translating down to whatever automapper is trying to execute.

Tried `AllowNull()` instead but then it just goes back to throwing `Unknown LINQ expression of type 'Default'`.

Answer (score 0):

AM targets EF Core now and doesn't support EF6 anymore.
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/4205